# How do I show that if is normal, then if T is a projection then it must be an orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, adjoint-operators

T is an operator on a finite dimensional inner product space. How do I show that if T is a projection, then it must be an orthogonal projection?

I know I have to use the fact that $T^*T=TT^*$, and I what I want to do is to show that $||T(x)||<||x||$ for all $x\in V$ with the inner product, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Do you know that a normal matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable? Do you know what the possible eigenvalues of a projection are?

Comment: So would I apply spectral theorem here to do the proof?

Comment: That's a way to do it, yes.

Comment: See my answer in     http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698087/proving-consequences-of-spectral-decomposition-of-normal-operator